# Не работает директива @

Tags: laravel, blade

Взял пример с [документация Laravel](http://laravel.su/docs/5.3/blade)
Скопировал код шаблона:

```html
<!-- Файл resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

и дочерней страницы:

```html
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    @

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

В результате получил следующий вывод :

> @
>
> This is appended to the master sidebar.
>
> This is my body content.

Хотя, на сколько я понял, вместо @ должно было подставиться содержимое секции sidebar, определенное в шаблоне, то есть должно было быть выведено следующее:

> This is the master sidebar.
>
> This is appended to the master sidebar.
>
> This is my body content.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ошибка в документации. Вместо `@` должно быть `@parent`

Это можно увидеть из этого примера в официальной документации: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#extending-a-layout

Comment: Создал issue: https://github.com/LaravelRUS/docs/issues/195

Comment: Спасибо, нужно было мне свериться с оригиналом